# Certificate in windows .pfx file has EKU issue

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have developed an application in phonegap and now I want to release it for windows phones. But as we know that since Windows 10 was introduced we have to make a **.pfx** file to sign an application.

I have created a certificate with OpenSSL and as I try to build my application with that key I am getting this error:

> Error - Your Windows Signing Key must have an EKU (Enhanced Key Usage)
>   property of "Code Signing"

I don't know what does exactly mean. Can anyone please help me out for this?

Comment: EKU is an extension that you can put in a certificate and some applications may require that extension when using the certificate. You can use openssl config files to include it (and you'll have to generate another certificate)

Comment: I would recommend to purchase code signing certificate from a globally trusted commercial CA. Self-signed certificates has vary little value and are acceptable for testing purposes.

Comment: @Hugo : can you please how can i use openssl config file? as I have no idea about open ssl

Comment: I don't use the config file very often, so I'd recommend you  google :) - maybe this can help: https://www.phildev.net/ssl/opensslconf.html

Answer (score 5):

EKU (Enhanced Key Usage) is certificate Extensions which determine what the certificate is intended to be used for. For signing other applications, Windows expects the cert to contain Code Signing EKU extension.

I suppose you are using a self signed certificate. You can use following commands to generate a pfx file which would contain a certificate for your use. Although I'm not sure if a self signed certificate can be used to push an application on windows app store

First of all save following content in a file name "code_signing". This file is configuration file for your certificate. Change the fields under "my dn"

```
[ req ]
prompt             = no
distinguished_name = my dn

[ my dn ]
commonName = secure.example.com
countryName = XX
localityName = XXX
organizationName = Org Name
organizationalUnitName = BU Name
stateOrProvinceName = YY
emailAddress = mail@example.com
name = name
surname = surName
givenName = name

[code_signing]
extendedKeyUsage = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3
```

The last line extendedKeyUsage = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 specifies the EKU for code Signing.
Now use following to generate a private key and certificate using above config file

```
openssl req -x509 -config code_signing -extensions 'code_signing' -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private.key -out certificate.crt
```

Now use the generated private.key and certificate.crt to generate your pfx file

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out codeSigning.pfx -inkey private.key -in certificate.crt
```