# .pfx files not valid for windows 10 release in phonegap

Tags: cordova, openssl, release, windows-10-mobile

I have made an application using phonegap now I want to release in windows store but the thing is that since windows 10 has introduced they require .pfx certificate signing we have to create a signed certificate.

now as per this link http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/signing/windows/#winphone8 it redirect to windows page where mentined technology is (according to windows) **deprecated**.

I tried to make by openssl but when I build it with it I am getting error that "The certificate specified is not valid for signing. " I am stuck at this point please help me to resolve this.

**NOTE:**
I have also tried self signed certificate but then it ask for eku is not valid hence I have followed this link [Certificate in windows .pfx file has EKU issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393219/certificate-in-windows-pfx-file-has-eku-issue/43427483#43427483) but seems it is also not working too.
Please help me out.
Is there any special guied-line for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Openssl or powershell won't work as expected. Do it this way.

Install the Microsoft Visual Studio (any), you will have option to choose what packages to install. Make sure you install the "Windows Software Development Kit".

Search for Visual Studio Command prompt (this is different from the usual cmd.exe). Then run the following codes.

Replace the **CN value** (can be found on MS Developer page > settings ) and replace **app_name** and **password**.

```
makecert.exe -n "CN=XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX" -r -eku "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13" -e "01/01/2020" -h 0 -sv app_name.pvk app_name.cer

pvk2pfx -pvk app_name.pvk -pi password -spc app_name.cer -pfx app_name.pfx -po password
```

Now set phonegap version on your config.xml to cli-6.5.0

Tested and works perfectly.